# SwiftUI ObservedObject not updating across views

Tags: swiftui, observedobject

I cannot get observable object model to work.

I have a simple demo of two views and a view model.  The view model is;

```
import Foundation

class Score: ObservableObject {

    @Published var total = 0

}
```

A button view to add one to the total;

```
struct ScoreButton: View {
    @ObservedObject var score = Score()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            score.total += 1
        }, label: {
            Text("Add 1 to Total")
        })
    }
}
```

Then a start view to show the results;

```
struct OBDemo: View {

    @ObservedObject var result = Score()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScoreButton()
                .padding()
            Text("Total = \(result.total)")

        }
    }
}
```

If I put the class, button and start view in one file it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the two *different* instances of `Score`:

```
struct ScoreButton: View {
    @ObservedObject var result = Score() // instance #1
```

```
struct OBDemo: View {
    @ObservedObject var result = Score() // instance #2
```

You need to use the same instance in both views - pass the `@ObservedObject` to the child view:

```
struct OBDemo: View {
    @ObservedObject var result = Score() // create in the parent view

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScoreButton(result: result) // <- pass to the child view
                .padding()
            Text("Total = \(result.total)")

        }
    }
}

struct ScoreButton: View {
    @ObservedObject var score: Score // declare only

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            score.total += 1
        }, label: {
            Text("Add 1 to Total")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  How do I update the preview for ScoreButton? static var previews: some View {
        ScoreButton(score: #?#)

Comment: @Jmcg You can do `ScoreButton(score: Score())`